# How can I get unlabeled volume drive total size by C#?

Tags: c#, windows, diskspace, disk-partitioning, driveinfo

I'm using C# to investigate windows drives.

How can I get the size of volume with RAW Partition?

Comment: You could use WMI in order to get the information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

First have something to represent a volume:

```
public class Volume
{
    public Volume(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
        ulong freeBytesAvail, totalBytes, totalFreeBytes;
        if (GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(path, out freeBytesAvail, out totalBytes, out totalFreeBytes))
        {
            FreeBytesAvailable = freeBytesAvail;
            TotalNumberOfBytes = totalBytes;
            TotalNumberOfFreeBytes = totalFreeBytes;
        }
    }

    public string Path { get; private set; }

    public ulong FreeBytesAvailable { get; private set; }
    public ulong TotalNumberOfBytes { get; private set; }     
    public ulong TotalNumberOfFreeBytes { get; private set; }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string volumeName, out ulong freeBytesAvail,
        out ulong totalBytes, out ulong totalFreeBytes);
}
```

Next have a simple volume enumerator:

```
public class VolumeEnumerator : IEnumerable<Volume>
{
    public IEnumerator<Volume> GetEnumerator()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2048);
        IntPtr volumeHandle = FindFirstVolume(sb, (uint)sb.MaxCapacity);
        {
            if (volumeHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                yield break;
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    yield return new Volume(sb.ToString());
                    sb.Clear();
                }
                while (FindNextVolume(volumeHandle, sb, (uint)sb.MaxCapacity));
                FindVolumeClose(volumeHandle);
            }
        }

    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindFirstVolume([Out] StringBuilder lpszVolumeName,
       uint cchBufferLength);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool FindNextVolume(IntPtr hFindVolume, [Out] StringBuilder lpszVolumeName, uint cchBufferLength);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool FindVolumeClose(IntPtr hFindVolume);
}
```

Finally example code to use it:

```
foreach (Volume v in new VolumeEnumerator())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, Free bytes available {1} Total Bytes {2}", v.Path,
        v.FreeBytesAvailable, v.TotalNumberOfBytes);
}
```

This is all from building P/Invokes into the [Volume Management API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365730(v=vs.85).aspx). If this isn't what you want, you'll likely find the specific information there.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. It show me the right information about the ntfs but For all RAW partition its show me "Free bytes available 0 Total Bytes 0".

Comment: @user436862 because for unallocated partitions there is no available bytes.